# Tensorflow: How do I structure datasets to find vector output?

Tags: python, tensorflow, reverse-engineering, shapes

I'm a Tensorflow Newbie. 
I am trying to find weight of holdings given value ratios for each holding. 
Ex) Input has 1000 stocks and each has three values : A, B, C. 
Output is weight for each stock, adding up to 1
There are 10 such datasets, each for different date.

How do I set up appropriate shape and placeholders and prediction? 
Thinking to set up loss function and use optimizer to train but confusing.
Any insights/references will be helpful to structure this. Thanks.